# Dynamically add tooltips to kendo grid rows of a column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-tooltip

I have a column with some notes displaying in the rows. Since the notes are huge, I have cut short the notes in the controller itself and sent that to my aspx page. What I want to achieve is, I want to display the complete notes in the form of a tool tip on mouse over of the grid row ( or if possible exactly on cell ). Is there any way to achieve this?  Any help would be highly appreciated.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Apologies for the wrong title. The title must be something like this " Add a tool tip for dynamic content in kendo grid " .

Comment: Why don't you accept your solution ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Posting the answer as it might help anyone.

I got that working after doing this...

```
columns.Bound(p => p.partialNotes).Title("Description").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left" }).Width("8%").HtmlAttributes(new { title =  "#= completeNotes #" });
```

I have just added  *HtmlAttributes(new { title =  "#= completeNotes #" })*

So now when I place the mouse over the Description column data , I get the complete Notes as a tool tip.

Answer (score 3):

Using a 3rd party widget is also a possibility. I've added [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) tips to column headers like this [image]

KendoUI grid column array item

```
{
    field:"property",
    headerTemplate:kendo.template($("#h_Entity_property").html())
},
```

The header template

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/Craga89-qTip2-bfcc9ef/dist/jquery.qtip.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/Craga89-qTip2-bfcc9ef/util/qtip.util.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/Craga89-qTip2-bfcc9ef/dist/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/Craga89-qTip2-bfcc9ef/util/Dialogues.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/Craga89-qTip2-bfcc9ef/util/Qtip2Util.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="h_Entity_property">
    Property
    <img onclick="Qtip.local(this, 'i_Entity_property')" src="img/info.gif"/>
    <div id="i_Entity_property" style="display:none;">
        Elaborate a bit...
    </div>
</script>
```

Tooltip generator

```
var Qtip = {
    local:function (element, contentId) {
        $(element).qtip($.extend({}, qTipSharedOptions, {
                content:{
                    text:$('#' + contentId).html(),
                    title:{
                        text:' ',
                        button:true
                    }
                }
            }
        ));
    },
    ...
};

var qTipSharedOptions = {
    position:{
        at:'top right', // Position the tooltip above the link
        my:'bottom left',
        viewport:$(window), // Keep the tooltip on-screen at all times
        effect:false // Disable positioning animation
    },
    style:{
        classes:'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow'
    },
    show:{
        ready:true,
        event:false,
        solo:true // Only show one tooltip at a time
    },
    hide:false
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below:

```
$("#Kendo-grid-div-id").kendoTooltip({
    filter: "td:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(3)", //comma separated multiple columns
    position: "bottom",     //possible values: bottom,top,left,right,center
    content: function(e){
      var content = e.target.html();
      return content;
    }
  }).data("kendoTooltip");
```